# Moving image link out of head in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

As you can see I have icons in the top right corner (these icons are part of the background image I have in my CSS code). I want to move the little horse icon (red) up over the "DRF Go!" icon, but I can't get it over the green line. The things in the blue square are all my html and the rest is not.

I've tried to do it in the JS code (which I've added in as a comment here), but then I don't know how to move or change the size of it.

(If there is an easier code to use or if it can be done in my CSS or JS code please tell me)

Picture of page:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Lindrideklub/?fref=ts" target="_blank">
  <img src="LOGO.png" style="margin-left:130%; width:42px; padding-top:1px; height:42px;border:0">
</a>

<head>
  <title>Our Company</title>
  <link href="Forside.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav id="nav01"></nav>
<div style="margin-left:20%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">

<div id="main">
  <h1>Lindeg&aring;rdens Rideklub</h1> 
  <h2>Velkommen!</h2>
  <br>
  <p>Sp&oslash;rgsm&aring;l kan viderestilles til drakenia7@gmail.com</p>
  <footer id="foot01"></footer>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code if you need it

```
body {
background-image: url("Forside.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 1920px;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: top; 
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #cccccc; 
color: #696969;                     /*tekst*/
padding: 230px;                     /*Ryk side ned*/
padding-left: 180px;                /*Ryk side mod højre*/
padding-right: 420px;               /*Ryk side mod venstre*/  
}

#main {
padding: 5px;                       /*Ryk tekst ned*/
padding-left:  15px;                /*Ryk tekst mod højre*/
padding-right: 15px;                /*Ryk tekst mod venstre*/
background-color: #ffffff;          /*Baggrunds farve til felt*/
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

h1 {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
border-bottom: 3px solid green;     /*Linje under overskrift*/
color: #666666;                     /*Overskrifts farve*/
font-size: 30px;
}

table {
width:100%;
}

table, th , td {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}

th {
text-align: left; 
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul#menu {
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 11px;
padding-left: 333px;
}

ul#menu li {
display: inline;
margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#menu li a {
/*background-color: #ffffff;*/
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: black;
}
```

And the JS code

```
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
"<p>" + new Date().getFullYear() + " LNB. All rights reserved.</p>";

document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='Forside.html'>Forside</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Omos.html'>Om os</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='maps.html'>Find os</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='nyheder.html'>Nyheder</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='Kontakt.html'>Kontakt</a></li>" +
"</ul>";

/*var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'LOGO.png';
  img.onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/Lindrideklub';
};
  document.body.appendChild(img);*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `position:absolute` and set `top` and `left` so it matches the 'box' you want.

Comment: Is that not CSS though? I have no idea how to get the link in the css

Comment: yes it is CSS.The way i would do it, would be:  create a `<div>` and put the image as `background` , move it where it should be, create the link with `<a>` tag inside the `<div>` and set(for the link) `display:block` .

Comment: I still can't get it over the green line

Comment: Oh! I figured it out. I used your suggestion and it worked, I just messed up a bit at first. But it works now so thank you very much!

Comment: Using the code you provided this is the result of what i described above. (dont mind the missing logo) [test page](http://caldera.iks.gr/test/test.html)
 check the `.horse` class using your Inspector.

Comment: Oh perfect ! Don't mind my latest answer then. My internet died for a minute and dind't see your answer

Answer (score 0):

PUT this "horse" element in the same `<div>` as this three icons, then it will go at the top, then just make position you want.
Or give us jsfidle with full code, and we will help you

Comment: There are no "three icnos". They are a part of the big picture.

But I figured it out. I used Segmentations suggestion and it worked, I just messed up a bit at first. But it works now.
But thank you for helping!